# The visualforce page's tag in visual Studio doesn’t have automatic color style

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforcedx-cli, visualstudiocode

[image]

The tag in visual-force page should be in different color, I can not find similar situation on google, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I am so stupid, I found I did not enable visualforce in extention pack.

Comment: You need not be self-deprecating. Everyone's made simple mistakes like this from time to time. Consider it a learning experience.

Comment: Thanks Mm, you can choose your answer as the best answer as well, it just helped me and saved a lot of my time.